# Python use case dataframes

Tags: python

I have this use case in python where my csv file looks like this. The records are added dynamically to the csv file.

```
taskid, priority, receivedtime    
123, P1, 2018-12-05 10:00:00.000000    
234, P1, 2018-12-05 10:20:00.000000    
345, P1, 2018-12-05 10:30:00.000000
```

All the values are in the string format

I need to store it in a python dataframe and add an extra column which shows 10 minutes added to the time.

```
taskid, priority, recievedtime, followuptime    
123, P1, 2018-12-05 10:00:00.000000, 2018-12-05 10:10:00.000000    
234, P1, 2018-12-05 10:20:00.000000, 2018-12-05 10:30:00.000000    
345, P1, 2018-12-05 10:30:00.000000, 2018-12-05 10:40:00.000000
```

An infinite loop is run and if the followuptime is equal to the systemtime I need to add 10 minutes extra to the followuptime.

Note that the recievedtime is updated to the current systemtime when I start working on the uscase

Can somebody help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to read the newly added lines from the file immediately, as they get added?

Comment: yes. I want to read the newly added lines too.

Comment: This is not an easy task at all. The solution may be system-dependent. What is your operating system?

Comment: Ubuntu. I think I just need to match the system time with the follow-up time with an error of + or - 1 minute

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.to_datetime(recievedtime)
df['followuptime']= df['recievedtime']+timedelta(minutes=10)
```

Firstly convert your recievedtime into datetime by using :
and then use time delta to add 10 minutes

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I want to read the newly added lines from the file immediately, as they get added? If I receive a record in the csv with the same taskid with prioity P1, I need to update the first record follow up by time by adding 10 min and remove the last record added. If I recieve a record with the same record with the same Task id but with priority P2, I need to stop updating the time and change the status to P2.